# Python: split list of strings to a list of lists of strings by length with a nested comprehensions

Tags: python, nested, list-comprehension

I've got a list of strings and I'm trying to make a list of lists of strings by string length.

i.e.

```
['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']
```

becomes

```
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
```

I've accomplished this like so:

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']
lsts = []
for num in set(len(i) for i in lst):
    lsts.append([w for w in lst if len(w) == num])
```

I'm fine with that code, but I'm trying to wrap my head around comprehensions. I want to use nested comprehensions to do the same thing, but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> [[w for w in L if len(w) == num] for num in set(len(i) for i in L)]
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
```

Also, `itertools` is likely to be a little more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
lst = ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']
lst.sort(key=len) # does not make any change on this data,but
                  # all strings of given length must occur together


from itertools import groupby
lst = [list(grp) for i,grp in groupby(lst, key=len)]
```

results in

```
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
```

Comment: stable sort... `key=len` (also on groupby)

Comment: @JBernardo: thanks, I was thinking about that but you beat me to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

That is for all lengths from 1 to maximum (some of lists will be empty if there are no strings of that length in the `a` list):

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']
>>> m = max(len(x) for x in a)
>>> print [[x for x in a if len(x) == i + 1] for i in range(m)]
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
```

But if you want to have only lists for the lengths that are in `a` you must use `set(len(i) for i in lst)` instead of range.

```
>>> print [[x for x in a if len(x) == i] for i in set(len(k) for k in a)]
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abc']]
```

There is no difference for the list `['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']`. But if you change it a little bit, e.g so: `[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abcd']]`, you will see the difference:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abcd']
>>> print [[x for x in a if len(x) == i] for i in set(len(k) for k in a)]
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], ['abcd']]

>>> print [[x for x in a if len(x) == i + 1] for i in range(max(len(x) for x in a))]
[['a', 'b'], ['ab'], [], ['abcd']]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
L=['a','b','ab','abc']
result = [ [ w for w in L if len(w) == n] for n in set(len(i) for i in L)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import groupby

mylist = ['a', 'b', 'ab', 'abc']
[list(vals) for key, vals in groupby(mylist, lambda L: len(L))]
```

*note that since groupby only works on adjacent elements - you may need to force a sort on mylist with key=len)*

- returns an iterator with key (which will be length) and vals which is another iterator containing data in that key group.
- then converts the iterator of data into a list
- the outside list becomes built from the above
  -